# Bootstrap brand image overlapping container below the nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to include a **400 x 100 png logo** as a Navbar Brand image in Bootstrap 5. However, The logo appears to be a bit too big and even if I reduce the size of the logo, it still overlaps the black container and text input box underneath the Navbar in desktop view. In mobile devices, the logo and associated navbar overlaps even more. Also, the toggle button on the right is not aligned horizontally with the brand image on the left. I would like them to be on the same line. Attaching some screenshots for clarity. Can someone please help?

**Desktop View**

[image]

**Mobile View**

[image]

I would also want the brand image to be more aligned to the left in the mobile view. I am atatching the HTML code for review.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Localhost Site - Classroom Attendance</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Testing HTML 5 and Bootstrap 5">
  <meta name="keywords" content="html5,bootstrap5">
  <meta name="author" content="classroom">
  <!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
    <!-- Navbar Brand -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="media/fadmeter-logo.png" alt="Classroom Logo" width="250" height="62.5">
     </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Toggler/Collapsible Button -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto ms-sm-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-2 align-items-end">
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <form action="#">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
        </form>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Code Input Area -->
  <div class="container rounded mt-5 pt-3 pb-1 bg-dark text-white" style="width:400px">
   <form action="#">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">#</span>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Code">
     <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Headline and Description -->
  <div class="container">
   <h3>My Headline Text</h3>
   <p><span style="color:blue">Localhost</span> is a test page for HTML 5 and Bootstrap 5.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Headline and Description -->
  <div class="row mx-5">
   <div class="col-sm-3 mt-2">
    <div class="card text-center bg-warning">
     <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="media/1.png" style="width: 96px" alt="1">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Class 1</h5>
      <p class="card-text">All students in class room 1.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 mt-2">
    <div class="card text-center bg-info">
     <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="media/2.png" style="width: 96px" alt="2">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Class 2</h5>
      <p class="card-text">All students in class room 2.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 mt-2">
    <div class="card text-center bg-warning">
     <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="media/3.png" style="width: 96px" alt="3">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Class 3</h5>
      <p class="card-text">All students in class room 3.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 mt-2">
    <div class="card text-center bg-info">
     <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="media/4.png" style="width: 96px" alt="4">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Class 4</h5>
      <p class="card-text">All students in class room 4.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion provided by @Minhaj. I tweaked my code and it works fine now. I incorrectly placed the brand image in a separate div outside the navbar div. This is my new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Localhost Site - Classroom Attendance</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Testing HTML 5 and Bootstrap 5">
  <meta name="keywords" content="html5,bootstrap5">
  <meta name="author" content="classroom">
  <!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
    <!-- Navbar Brand -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="media/fadmeter-logo.png" alt="Fadmeter Logo" width="200" height="50" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0">
     </a>
     <!-- Toggler/Collapsible Button -->
     <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto ms-sm-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-2 align-items-end">
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <form action="#">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
        </form>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Code Input Area -->
  <div class="container rounded mt-5 pt-3 pb-1 bg-dark text-white" style="width:400px">
   <form action="#">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">#</span>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Code">
     <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Headline and Description -->
  <div class="container">
   <h3>My Headline Text</h3>
   <p><span style="color:blue">Localhost</span> is a test page for HTML 5 and Bootstrap 5.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Headline and Description -->
  <div class="row mx-5">
   <div class="col-sm-3 mt-2">
    <div class="card text-center bg-warning">
     <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="media/1.png" style="width: 96px" alt="1">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Class 1</h5>
      <p class="card-text">All students in class room 1.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 mt-2">
    <div class="card text-center bg-info">
     <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="media/2.png" style="width: 96px" alt="2">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Class 2</h5>
      <p class="card-text">All students in class room 2.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 mt-2">
    <div class="card text-center bg-warning">
     <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="media/3.png" style="width: 96px" alt="3">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Class 3</h5>
      <p class="card-text">All students in class room 3.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 mt-2">
    <div class="card text-center bg-info">
     <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="media/4.png" style="width: 96px" alt="4">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Class 4</h5>
      <p class="card-text">All students in class room 4.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width height from image tag and use "img-fluid" class in image tag.
Or in mobile view you can use position absolute

Comment: How do I reduce the size of the logo without using the width tag?